# Cannot build Docker images any more

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu, apt

I am having an issue with my Ubuntu 20 PC. So far I have used Docker frequently, however lately I cannot build *any* docker image any more.

The problem is when a Dockerfile has the usual RUN commands

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get remove -y x264 libx264-dev
RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y && apt-get install -y sudo clang-format wget apt-utils
```

Well, RUN apt-get update fails every time with

```
Err:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com'
Err:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:3 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1604/x86_64  InRelease
  Could not resolve host: developer.download.nvidia.com
Err:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Reading package lists...
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-backports/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-security/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1604/x86_64/InRelease  Could not resolve host: developer.download.nvidia.com
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

What could be happening here?

I remember once I had a similar problem and a reboot fixed it but not this time.

Comment: Restart your network or ping the above URLs in your PC. Are you asking from your PC or another device? Does your PC have proper internet connection and a DNS?

Comment: I am using a ubuntu PC. Yes the internet works (I can browse the internet no prob)

Comment: I know it’s a random shot in the dark have you tried a docker system prune?

Comment: @Jeef should I leave from my currently running containers to do that?

Comment: Q: Did you resolve the problem? Q: Is WSL in the mix?  If so, see if this WSL2/DNS workaround helps: [coltenkrauter/fix-wsl2-dns-resolution](https://gist.github.com/coltenkrauter/608cfe02319ce60facd76373249b8ca6)

Comment: probably stop everything and do a prune would be my guess